# Security features are missing in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Why security features are missing in my WSO2 DSS?

[image]

Do I need to install a feature? If yes, which one?

Comment: Could you please include exact DSS version you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.5.0 version of DSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIR the security features are now moved to Developer Studio. You can use Developer Studio to achieve those features. You may refer webinar in [1] which is for WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2015/12/how-to-secure-your-enterprise-services-with-wso2-esb-4.9/